# Making a black bar in BarChart when using GlassRectangle

Tags: charts

I use the command:

```
BarChart[{1, 2, 3}, ChartLegends -> {"a", "b", "c"}, 
 ChartStyle -> {Blue, Red, Black}, ChartLayout -> "Stacked", 
 ChartElementFunction -> "GlassRectangle"]
```

But the result is that the black bin comes out gray:

[image]

Using RGBColor or Lighter/Darker did not help. The "GlassRectangle" look is very appealing but I do need it to be black or at least much darker.
Any ideas?
Many thanks,
Dan

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Read the [faq]!
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: I get a black bar with *Mathematica* 10.0.2 under Win 7.

Comment: Works as as expected with 10.0.2.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (December 4, 2014).

Comment: Works as expected: 10.0.0.0, Windows 8.1 x86-64.

Comment: Works as expected on 10.1 Windows 8.1 64 bit.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem can't be reproduced by others and the OP doesn't provide the version of OS and *Mathematica* used.

Comment: OP is using V9.0.0.

Comment: @brett. You mean that in v9 there is a bug with GlassRectangle?

Comment: I get a black bar in V10.2 and V9.0.1.  I can't check V9.0.0.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries V9.0.0 used some different code for GlassRectangle to try to maintain the glass effect better, but it had too much effect on the specified color, and was reverted for V9.0.1.

Answer (score 1):

On my computer Windows 7, Mathematica 9, your code renders a perfectly black bar! To understand if problem may be OS or Mathematica version related, please specify OS and Mathematica version.

[image: Result of your code on my computer]

Comment: Perfect in *Mathematica* version 10.1 on a Mac Pro running OS X.